# Linear Algebra Quick Question (Yes or No)

Tags: linear-algebra

Question 1: Gramm Schmidt, if a span of vectors are not orthogonal to each other we will use this process. My question is if we have 3 vectors that are not orthogonal to one another, do we have to find each of the orthogonal complement to a single vector? Using the 3 vectors, since vector 2 and 3 are not orthogonal to each other or orthogonal to vector 1. I would need to find the O-comp of vector2 = vector 2 - the projection of vector 2 onto vector 1. After that I would need to do the orthogonal complement of O-comp of vector3 = vector 3 - projection of vector 3 onto vector 1 and 2. OR can I combine it in one step as in. O-comp of vector3 = vector 3 - projection of vector 3 onto vector 1 and 2. The second option feels wrong because vector 2 is not orthogonal to vector 1 though.

Question 2: Before finding the projection on to a subspace. What happens if I get a question like if I have to find the span of the subspace of a matrix? Do I look at the Column space for the basis? 
 The question can be rewritten as "Projecting onto a matrix".

Comment: For question 1, I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you confused on how to do Gram Schmidt or when to apply it?

Comment: I just need confirmation if I need to find the orthogonal complement of vector 2 and vector 3 onto vector 1 OR if I have to first find the orthogonal complement of vector 2 onto vector 1 and then find the orthogonal complement of vector 3 onto vector 1 and 2.

Comment: If you have three vectors it does not matter which vector you pick first, second, then third. Does that answer your question?

Comment: So, if I want to find the orthogonal basis, I can just project 1 of the vectors onto the other 2?

Comment: You would follow the GSOP algorithm. Choose a vector to start (usually one like $[1,0,0]$, for example, is computationally nicer). Then use GSOP to find an orthogonal vector. You then use GSOP again, using the resulting second vector, to find a third orthogonal vector.

Comment: Okay, so it was the first option. I would need to find the orthogonal complement twice if I have 3 non orthogonal vectors. Also, last question, does the orthogonal basis have to be orthonormal?

Comment: A basis is orthonormal if and only if it is both orthogonal and all the vectors in said basis are of unit length. So the answer is no. You would have to normalize each vector.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s call the original vectors $v_i$ and the corresponding vectors produced by G-S $u_i$. It’s true that the spans of $\{u_1,u_2\}$ and $\{v_1,v_2\}$ are identical, so it doesn’t matter whether you use the former or latter to compute the orthogonal projection of $v_3$ onto this space. However, if $v_1$ and $v_2$ aren’t orthogonal, this projection isn’t simply the sum of the projections onto the individual vectors. That computation involves at least as much work as orthogonalizing $v_1$ and $v_2$ in the first place, so you might as well use $u_1$ and $u_2$ do avoid a duplication of effort.